# Facebook share APi not working

Tags: javascript, facebook

I try to share a page using this code

```
FB.ui(
 {
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/'
}, function(response){})
```

after i run this Initialization code

```
FB.init({
    appId      : 'my-app-id',
    status     : true,
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.1'
});
```

And it works only the first time i press the button on my page. the next time I'm trying to
click the button that call the FB.ui function i get this error in the console

Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.mywebsite.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

If i run the page in incognito mode everything works fine.

I tried a number of solutions presented here on the site and I could not solve the problem
Does anyone have suggestions ?

Comment: can we get a testlink?

Comment: sure https://www.ramkol.co.il/bizcopy/332

Comment: works fine for me, even when i click again (id=facebook_biz).

Comment: its work only if you not connected to facebook

Comment: i AM connected to facebook. you mean it´s NOT working when you are not connected to facebook?

Comment: NO, if i click on the #facebook_biz before the page finish load its resources its work but after that it say in the console
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com" from accessing ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that FB.getLoginStatus function can't work good with the FB.ui function. 
so i solved the problem by creating function that open share windows instead of using the FB.ui function

```
function facebook_share(link){
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(520/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(430/2);
    window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=="+link, "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top="+top+", left="+left+", width=520, height=430");
}
```